# Counterexample to divisibility of subgroup indices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, with $H,K\subset G$ subgroups of finite index. Show by counterexample that the index $[H:H\cap K]$ need not divide $[G:K]$.

It's pretty easy to prove that $[H:H\cap K]\le [G:K]$ using group actions. I've considered all the cyclic and product groups I can think of to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G=S_3$ and $H$ and $K$ be two distinct subgroups of order $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$Just to clarify where do examples come from, it is quite easy to prove that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the (left) cosets of $H \cap K$ in $H$, and the cosets of $K$ in the *subset* 
$$
H K = \Set{ h k : h \in H, k \in K}.
$$
If $H K$ is a subgroup, then the above yields the equality 
$$
\Size{H : H \cap K} = \Size{H K : K},
$$
and the latter divides $$\Size{G : K} = \Size{G : H K} \cdot \Size{H K : K}$$ by Lagrange. So you are looking for your example among the cases where $H K$ is *not* a subgroup, as illustrated by the accepted answer.

Comment: Indeed, that was exactly my thought process. In particular, you want both $H$ and $K$ not to be normal. (I started to type something like this but got too lazy.)

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer!